# Make greek numeration

Tags: numbering, counters, greek

How can I print a counter in the greek alphabet?

```
\newcounter{nc}
\setcounter{nc}{2}
\arabic{nc} %print 2
\greek{nc} %I'd like to see \beta
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package [`moreenum`](https://ctan.org/pkg/moreenum) is *actually* intended to provide a few more styles for enumeration, but it defines a greek numeral system *en passant*. I guess it is probably the easiest way to make use of this package and define your counter:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{moreenum}

\newcounter{greeknumber}
\setcounter{greeknumber}{1}

\begin{document}

\greek{greeknumber}
\Greek{greeknumber}

\stepcounter{greeknumber}

\greek{greeknumber}
\Greek{greeknumber}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way: The greek letters employed from the package are generated from the standard mathematical greek letters like `\alpha` or `\beta`. IMHO it would be great if this could be turned into a package that makes use of `utf8`-greek letters of the main font, if available, or even made a standard counter-style in latex.ltx! In Greek philology it is sometimes the case that certain books are enumerated that way until this day, e.g. the eleventh book of the *Odyssee* is book λ. My skills are, alas, not advanced enough to achieve this.